# Melave d'Malka on Motze Yom Tov

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, melave-malka

Is there an obligation to have Melave DMalka on *Motzei Yom Tov* like *Motzei Shabbos*?

(Question is based on the Rambam (Shabbos 30:5), who includes the obligation of *Melave dMalka* with *Kovod Shabbos*:

> מסדר אדם שולחנו בערב שבת, ואף על פי שאינו צריך אלא לכזית. וכן מסדר
>   שולחנו במוצאי שבת, ואף על פי שאינו צריך אלא לכזית, כדי לכבדו בכניסתו
>   וביציאתו.

The Rambam also rules (Yom Tov, 6:15) that the obligation of *Kovod* applies equally to Shabbos and Yom Tov:

> כשם שמצוה לכבד שבת ולענגה, כך כל ימים טובים שנאמר: לקדוש ה' מכובד, וכל
>   ימים טובים נאמר בהם מקרא קדש. וכבר ביארנו הכיבוד והעינוג בהל' שבת

Accordingly, anything which is required for Kovod Shabbos (and Melave dMalka is included) should be equally relevant on Yom Tov.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a dispute in the *poskim*.

**The position that one is obligated**:
The Chazon Ish (quoted in Orchos Rabbeinu v.2 p.110, and in טעמא דקרא, הנהגות החזו״א אות י״ח) was *mapkid* to eat *melaveh demalke* on Motze Yom Tov.

The Brisker Rav was asked (פניני רבינו הגרי״ז, עמ׳ רמ״ב) if there is an obligation for *melave dmalka* on Motzei Yom Tov, and he responded: "אינני יודע למה לא" (I'm not sure if he meant to *pasken* that there is, or although the accepted *halacha* is that not, he doesn't understand why it should be different to Shabbos).

See also Tashbatz Katan (§82), who insinuates that there is a seuda on Motze Yom Tov:

> וכשהוא מבדיל במוצאי שבת או מוצאי יו״ט על שלחנו, מכסה את הפס כמו שעושים בשב, ואמנם אינו מצריך ב׳ לחמים במוצאי שבת קדש או מוצאי יו״ט

**The Position that one is not obligated:** However, *Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchoso* (63:4) rules that there is no obligation on Motzei Yom Tov.

R' Moshe Shternbuch *shlit"a* (*Moadim V'Zmanim* v7 §153, and *Teshuvos V'Hanhagos* v6, §120) explains the difference between Shabbos and Yom Tov:

(a) On Shabbos there is no *hekker* that the Seuda *lkovod shabbos*, so Chazal instituted a special *seuda* on Motzei Shabbos. On Yom Tov, however, where there is the extra בשר ויין (as well as the מאריכין בסעודה, as per the Rambam), there was no need to institute the separate *seuda*.

(b) On Yom Tov, there is no *neshama yeseira*. (see Tosfos Beitza 33b, and Pesachim 102b).

(c) One should have hot food on Motze Shabbos (Shabbos 119b) to show that one could not heat up food on Shabbos. On Yom Tov, this does not apply.

The *Leket Yosher* (OCH p.58) gives testimony that his Rebbi, the *Terumas Hadeshen*, did not eat *Melave dMalka* on Motzei Yom Tov.

Comment: Perhaps Isru Chag functions to melaveh out the chag even if it's not specifically at night.