Isru Chag on Shabbos
Sukkah 45b:

״אִסְרוּ חַג בַּעֲבוֹתִים עַד קַרְנוֹת הַמִּזְבֵּחַ״. אָמַר רַבִּי יִרְמְיָה מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן יוֹחַי, וְרַבִּי יוֹחָנָן מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן הַמָּחוֹזִי מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן הַמָּכוֹתִי: כׇּל הָעוֹשֶׂה אִיסּוּר לֶחָג בַּאֲכִילָה וּשְׁתִיָּה, מַעֲלֶה עָלָיו הַכָּתוּב כְּאִילּוּ בָּנָה מִזְבֵּחַ וְהִקְרִיב עָלָיו קׇרְבָּן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אִסְרוּ חַג בַּעֲבוֹתִים עַד קַרְנוֹת הַמִּזְבֵּחַ״.


Bind [isru] with dense-leaved branches [ba’avotim] on the Festival until the horns of the altar” (Psalms 118:27), which alludes to both the binding of the lulav and to the myrtle branch, referred to in the Torah as the branch of a dense-leaved tree [anaf etz avot]. Rabbi Yirmeya said in the name of Rabbi Shimon ben Yoḥai, and Rabbi Yoḥanan said in the name of Rabbi Shimon HaMeḥozi, who said in the name of Rabbi Yoḥanan HaMakkoti: With regard to anyone who establishes an addition [issur] to the Festival on the day after the Festival by eating and drinking, the verse ascribes him credit as though he built an altar and sacrificed an offering upon it, as it is stated: “Add [isru] to the Festival with fattened animals [ba’avotim] until the horns of the altar.”

If the day following Yom Tov is Shabbos (as it was this year in the diaspora), is there any reason to increase in eating and drinking on Sunday (since doing so on Shabbos, which is already festive, might not demonstrate an “Issur Lachag”)?

Purim and Rosh Chodesh on shabbos have their meals pushed to Sunday, but here it's not a special isru chag obligation as much as extending the holiday. Probably more analogous to melava malka on Sunday yom tov. Can you source that there is any need to increase food on isru chag?

@DoubleAA I had never heard that Seudas Rosh Chodesh can be postponed to Sunday.

That's the source for pushing Purim to Sunday. Yerushalmi באלו אמרו מקדימין ולא מאחרין קריאת מגילה ותרומת שקלים מקדימין ולא מאחרין סעודת ראש חדש וסעודת פורים מאחרין ולא מקדימין If you don't eat Seudat Rosh Chodesh on Sunday it doesn't make sense to do that for Purim. Similarly if you don't skip tachanun on every Sunday second of the month, it makes no sense to skip it on Sunday 16 Adar even in a walled city

@DoubleAA I’m surprised that I’ve never seen either of these done. Do you have an explicit source for not saying Tachanun on Sunday following Rosh Chodesh?

There are no such sources since no one ever did any of that (until the last 1-2 centuries when making up excuses to skip tachanun became in vogue in certain non-conservative communities https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/112111/skip-tachanun-on-the-sunday-of-purim-meshulash#comment447685_112120 )

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104634/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104635/melave-dmalka-on-motze-yom-tov?rq=1#comment430579_104638

But postponing the seudah seems pretty clear cut; I shall have to reinstitute this. Being a member of said communities, I may just stop saying Tachanun too lol

Clear cut for the yerushalmi. The Bavli and the Rambam etc. don't mention such a rule and mistimatam the Seuda for RCh and Purim is on shabbat itself. It's common now to be machmir for the yerushalmi (for purim at least) since there's no downside, but it's not clear cut that it's ikkar hadin, let alone to be meikil about tachanun that the yerushalmi itself probably didn't agree with (it's a chiyuv seudah not a Yom Tov)

The Tur uses this Yerushalmi as proof that Seudas Rosh Chodesh is a chiyuv. See also Aruch Hashulchan O”CH 419.

Sure but again it's not %100 clear cut.

Bon appetit!!!!

Lol, thanks! :)
